# ZMQ Ratchet PUSH/PULL not working

Tags: php, sockets, zeromq, ratchet

I followed this tutorial [`socketo/push`](http://socketo.me/docs/push) to push messages from the server to the client in real time. I'm using the CodeIgniter framework. These are my files:

**`push-server.php`**

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); // Binding to 127.0.0.1 means
                                     // the only client that can connect
                                     // is itself
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessage'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server('0.0.0.0:8080', $loop);
/*
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means
                                   // remotes can connect
  */
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

I commented the **`$webSock->listen()`** line because it was throwing an error and in a git issue someone has commented that this was because an update in the react/zmq library, so that is the only line different to the tutorial.

**`controller.php`**

```
public function post()
{
    $entryData = array(
        'category' => 'kittensCategory',
        'title'    => 'Title'
    );

    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
    $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

    $socket->send(json_encode($entryData));
}
```

This is the function that I'm calling and that should push a message to my  pusher class but it does nothing.

I don't know what's the problem, my client is connecting correctly and the pusher is working good in the subscription method, so it has to be something in the push or the pull.

I have been trying to solve this for 2 weeks now but I don't have a clue, any comment would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: Rather use a call to an explicitly expressed address `$socket->connect( "tcp://` **`127.0.0.1`** `:5555");`

Comment: I already tried that with the same results: no error message, no success no nothing.

Comment: How many milliseconds do you wait before `->send()`-ing a first message, after the `->connect()` took place and how do you record and validate an Error-state after the calling the `->connect()` method?

Comment: I don't wait anytime before sending the message after the `->connect()`, currently i don't know how to debug that connection, how can I log it and record that Error-state?.

Comment: Best use the ZeroMQ tools -- `Stopwatch()` instance's `{ .start() | .stop() }-`methods, that provide measurements @ microsecond resolution ( 1E-6 [s] ). Similarly, ZeroMQ error-number is accesible via core/API call to detect actual Error-state. Finally - never, indeed NEVER try to use ZeroMQ infrastructure as a disposable. The costs of setup / release are not cheap and trying to ignore initial resources setup / final termination latencies leads to avoidable collisions. Setup your infrastructure well beforehand before any 1st `->send()` appears. Best stay as a systematically non-blocking design

Comment: Maybe the setup is the problem, currently i'm requiring the src/MyApp/pusher.php in my push-server.php file because if i don't do that when I try to run the server I got this error `Fatal error: Class 'MyApp\Pusher' not found in C:\wamp64\www\RatchetTest\bin\push-server.php on line 5`

Comment: Exact same problem here. I can see in tcpdump that the packages are going through. ZMQ/php is listening on the right address/port, and yet the 'message' event is never triggered.